# Facebook Share Button with return URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

Basically I want to use Facebook Share Button. And if a user shared the page with this button, I want to write it into my db.

Is there any property on Facebook Sharer like this. For example; after sharing go to http://www.test.com/Shared.aspx?UserdId=1

Comment: Why do you want to write it to your database?

Comment: You need to use Facebook's JavaScript SDK and hook into a sharing event. When this event is fired - make an ajax call to your server, redirect user to any URL etc.

Comment: I want to know which users shared this

Comment: The point of the share button is that users don’t have to log in to your app to be able to share something – and without login, you of course get no information about them whatsoever.